# Using the WMI Build Activity to call a remote Command Line command

Tags: c#, tfs, wmi, build-process, tfsbuild

So I'm working in a TFS Build Definition, in a custom build process that will execute some logic based on configurations the user chooses. I'm doing this as part of an effort to automate a test lab more fully and make it more self-service.

Specifically, I need to give the user the option to restart the SQL Server's Services prior to a test run, thus allowing all caches to be cleared and maintaining a stable start point for all test measurements.

In order to use something that isn't written by hand and is more fully tested than something I could hack together using `ServiceController` calls, I want to use `WMI` and the `WMI Build Activity` from the [TFSBuildExtensions](https://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/) project on Codeplex. Using this activity rather than coding my own custom activity also allows me access to some logging and error handling I would otherwise have to code myself. Additionally, using a WMI activity allows me to keep all of the logic at the `.XAML` layer, which is consistent with how everything else is done in the build process.

The problem is that the in-code documentation for the `WMI` activity is a little unclear. For example, I'm not seeing where it references the `MachineName` agrument it asks for in `Properties`, and as well I'm not quite sure how I am supposed to pass in MethodParameters for use on a remote machine. Do I just enter something like:

`CommandLine#~#Net Stop "MSSQLServer" /y`

Or what? The error I am seeing for that specific line is:

`'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of String)' because 'Char' is not derived from 'String' as required for the 'Out' generic parameter 'T' in 'Interface IEnumerable(Of Out T)'.`

I've read over some stuff about `WMI` but I am probably missing something about making it connect to a Win32 process to start.

Answer (score 0):

Why not executing a powershell  script or.command? This way it will be a minimal effort when you move to 2013 build templates.

Powershell has built in cmdlet for managing win services, even remotely.

Comment: It's not really an option for me to do that given the requirements of the project I'm working on, but I did think about doing that first and brought it up as an option. It would actually be simpler and a bit more efficient in certain respects.

Comment: Then consider using the SC.EXE command for managing local and remote Windows Services. It can be called using the InvokeProcess activity and could be much simpler than the WMI option.

Comment: Would that be able to handle stopping a service with dependencies?